# xslt 2.0 pass xml data to xsl:template by calling xsl:call-template

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to pass the xml data to a xslt template using xsl:with-param tag. This is the code:

**template:**

```
<xsl:template name="schedule">
    <xsl:param name="data" />
    <fo:block>
      <xsl:value-of select="$data" />
    </fo:block>
<xsl:template/>
```

Call the *schedule* template

```
<xsl:call-template name="schedule">
    <xsl:with-param name="data"> <xsl:value-of select="//root/scheduleData" /> </xsl:with-param>
<xsl:call-template>
```

**//root/scheduleData**  -> this contains the xml data.
The data received in schedule template is converted to string with only the data present in xml, even the xml tags are removed.

**xml data:**

```
<root>
   <tag1>567</tag1>
   <tag2>456</tag2>
   <scheduleData>
       <a>12</a>
       <b>34</b>
   </scheduleData>
   <scheduleData>
       <a>23</a>
       <b>45</b>
   </scheduleData>
   <scheduleData>
       <a>67</a>
       <b>89</b>
   </scheduleData>
</root>
```

data printed by this line - `<xsl:value-of select="$data" />` is:

```
1234
2345
6789
```

Is it possible to send xml data to templates? if its not possible what is the alternate way to achieve this. Thanks for help!

Comment: Data is converted to string because that's what `xsl:value-of` does. It's not clear what your expected result is (or why you even need to call a named template), so I am not going to suggest an alternative. Do note that if you send the original nodes to the template using `<xsl:with-param name="data" select="/root/scheduleData"/>` the result will still remain the same, because you use `xsl:value-of`  inside the template too.

Comment: in the template `name="schedule"` i want to iterate over the data using `xsl:for-each`, but as it converts to string it removes the xml tags(e.g `<a>` and `<b>`) and only data is available using `xsl:value-of`, it becomes difficult to parse and use it it any way.

Comment: Which of your shown code in the template named `schedule` intends `to iterate over the data`? Anyway, Michael gave you a clue to simply use `<xsl:with-param name="data" select="/root/scheduleData"/>` to select the `scheduleData` elements and bind them to the `data` parameter. So don't use `xsl:value-of` inside of `xsl:with-param`, simply use `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The data received in schedule template is converted to string with only the data present in xml, even the xml tags are removed.

Yes, that's exactly what `xsl:value-of` does.

You want

```
   <xsl:with-param name="data" select="//root/scheduleData" />
```